# Installing a haskell module and importing it in GHCI repl

Tags: haskell

On a Mac, I ran "cabal install MissingH". It seemed to install fine.

- How do I import and use the functions in MissingH
- How can I see the modules I have so far installed.
- In case "MissingH" is a part of something "Data.String" - why is this not shown anywhere?
- Is there an environment variable, that specifies a package PATH

I am looking for something like "cabal list" or "list modules" or "pip freeze" (I come from a Python background).

On a Mac, I ran "cabal install MissingH". It seemed to install fine.

Comment: `cabal` is more like `conda` or `poetry` and very different to `pip`. `cabal install --lib MissingH` to "install" a library (notice, that installing a library makes little sense, as they are not executable, unlike python's). `cabal repl --build-depend MissingH` to open a reple in which `MissingH` is available. `cabal list --installed` to list installed packages and `cabal freeze` exists. run `cabal help` and read the [docs](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.6/cabal-commands.html#cabal-v2-install) to get more info

Comment: in general you don't work with `cabal` nor `ghci` in your global environment, you create a `.cabal` file whithin a project.